# Mockito invalid use of Matchers exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following piece of code for which I'm writing unit test using Mockito:

```
      while (results.hasMore()) {
            found = true;
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute attr = attributes.get(LdapAttribute.CUSTOMER_GUID.getValue());
            setAttribute(attr);
            if (getAttribute() != null && cust.getCstCustGuid() == null) 
                cust.setCstCustGuid((String) attr.get());
      }
```

The unit test stub code:

```
    Mockito.doReturn(mockCustomer).when(ldap).getLDAPCustomer();
    Mockito.doReturn(mockCtx).when(ldap).getInitialDirContext();
    Mockito.doNothing().when(ldap).setAttribute(Mockito.any(Attribute.class));
    Mockito.doReturn(mockAttribute).when(ldap).getAttribute();
    Mockito.doReturn(mockSearchControls).when(ldap).getSearchControls();
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockSearchControls).setSearchScope(Mockito.anyInt());
    Mockito.when(mockCtx.search(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(SearchControls.class))).thenReturn(mockResults);
    Mockito.when(mockResults.hasMore()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(mockResults.next()).thenReturn(mockSearchResults);
    Mockito.when(mockSearchResults.getAttributes()).thenReturn(mockAttributes);
    Mockito.when(mockAttributes.get(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockAttribute);
    Mockito.when(mockAttribute.get()).thenReturn(Mockito.anyObject());

    Mockito.when(mockCustomer.getCstCustGuid()).thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockCustomer).setCstCustGuid(Mockito.anyString());
```

I'm getting `InvalidUseOfMatchers` exception at the line:

```
 Mockito.when(mockCustomer.getCstCustGuid()).thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `Mockito.anyString()` inside a `thenReturn()`. You can only use it when using `Mockito.when()` or `Mockito.verify()`.
Example: `Mockito.when(mockCustomer.getSomething(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(something);`

For your issue, you should replace the line  `Mockito.when(mockCustomer.getCstCustGuid()).thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());` by

**`Mockito.when(mockCustomer.getCstCustGuid()).thenReturn("");`**
or

**`Mockito.when(mockCustomer.getCstCustGuid()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(String.class));`**

Comment: This is the correct root cause—you can't use Matchers to return "any" instance—but you can't and shouldn't ever mock a String in real tests. Returning mocks of _mockable types you control_ is just fine.