# Mockito Invalid use of matchers Mock(Object.class) & anyString()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher, hamcrest

Ola,

I'm busy writing a unit test like

```
 monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), anyString());
```

When I execute this I get:

```
 Invalid use of argument matchers.
 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
```

So I tried:

```
monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), eq(anyString()));
```

But this gave

```
Invalid use of argument matchers.
0 matchers expected, 2 recorded.
```

I also tried to use

```
monitor.severe(any(MonitorEventType.class), anyString());
```

but this gives a null pointer.

What works is

```
   monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), "");
```

But thats not what I want.

My testMethod is :

```
@Test
public void testSevere() {
    monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), eq(anyString()));
    ArgumentCaptor<DefaultMonitoringEventImpl> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(DefaultMonitoringEventImpl.class);
    verify(event).fire(captor.capture());
    DefaultMonitoringEventImpl input = captor.getValue();
    assertThat(fetchMonitorLevel(input), equalTo(MonitorEventLevel.SEVERE.getDescription()));
}

private String fetchMonitorLevel(DefaultMonitoringEventImpl input) {
    Map<String, String> map = input.getMonitorEventWaardes().getWaardenLijst();
    return map.get(MonitorEvent.MONITOR_EVENT_LEVEL_KEY);
}
```

And the method under test is:

```
public void severe(MonitorEventType type, String message) {
    write(type, MonitorEventLevel.SEVERE, message, null);
}

@Asynchronous
public void write(MonitorEventType type, MonitorEventLevel level, String message, MonitorEventWaardes pEventWaardes) {
    event.fire(new DefaultMonitoringEventImpl(type, level, message, pEventWaardes));
}
```

What I want is that When I call monitor.severe with a random MonitorEventType and a random String that the "level" parameter in teh event.fire call is filled with the right value.

Comment: What is the goal exactly? What do you want to test?

Comment: show the method `severe`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto  the method severe looks like

public void severe(MonitorEventType type, String message) {
  write(type, MonitorEventLevel.SEVERE, message, null);
 }
here is the  complete test
public void testSevere() {
  monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), eq(anyString()));
  ArgumentCaptor<DefaultMonitoringEventImpl> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(DefaultMonitoringEventImpl.class);
  verify(event).fire(captor.capture());
  DefaultMonitoringEventImpl input = captor.getValue();
  assertThat(fetchMonitorLevel(input), equalTo(MonitorEventLevel.SEVERE.getDescription()));
 }

Comment: please add it to your question

Comment: even with it, it is still not clear what you want to achieve.  It seems that you want to capture arguments but for what purpose exactly?

Comment: You want to test that `severe` calls `write` with `MonitorEventLevel.SEVERE` as severity?

Comment: you will need also to show your class `MonitorEventLevel`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto See question,  I've added  the test methoid and the method under test.

Comment: sorry but you still not answering to all my questions: what do you want to do exactly? what is the method `write`? What is the class `MonitorEventLevel`? it is not possible to answer without all the answers

Comment: If it doesn't matter what String you put into that method then _that_ unit test is not actually testing _that_ constraint. So just use an instance of an arbitrary String like "". Even if different Strings have different expected results, if you are doing standard unit tests you would test the corner cases. Putting `anyString()` in the act part of the test will not cause JUnit to run a test against every possible String

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I've added some more code. What I want is that When I call monitor.severe with a random MonitorEventType and a random String that the "level" parameter in teh event.fire call is filled with the right value.

Comment: If you want to test a random string, then send a random string instead of an empty string. BTY using random values in unit test is not a good idea...

Comment: @EladTabak "" is something totally different than a random String, as I also explained in my question.

Comment: Then send a random string, or a mock(String.class). I think your question is not clear - are you trying to have the testing framework generate random string for you? or you just want to say "I don't care about the value of the string, as long as I'm verifying that the event was sent properly"?

Comment: @EladTabak I've added the  question this morning. maybe that explains it a little bit more. Next to this String is a final class and it's not possible to mock final classes.

Comment: What is `event`? What is `DefaultMonitoringEventImpl`? What is `Asynchronous`? It is your duty to provide everything to reproduce

Comment: @NicolasFilotto dont't think that it doesnt matter for my problem. but for the sake of completeness: DefaultMonitoringEventImpl is just an object.
event is from javax.enterprise.event.Event; Asynchronous is from javax.ejb.Asynchronous;

Comment: I can't reproduce how have you defined `event` and `monitor` in your test?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto    

        InjectMocks
 private final Monitor monitor = new Monitor();
Cant use the annotation symbol before mock and injectmocks in this comment

 Mock
 private Event<MonitorEvent> event;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito invalid use of Matchers exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128603/mockito-invalid-use-of-matchers-exception)

Comment: @DavidRawson If you take a good look at the question  , comments and the answer below , youll see that is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Bgvv1983 If you take a good look at my comment and that of @EladTabak  you'll see the answer is an elaboration of that, but you just weren't paying attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some basics:

- A *mock* is a replacement for a real object, that you can create using a mock framework. It records its interactions and verifies them for later.
- A *matcher* like `any`, `anyString`, or `eq` tells your mock framework (not your test framework or your system under test) what kind of calls are relevant for *stubbing* (telling your mock how to behave when its method is called) or *verifying* (asking your mock framework whether or not a certain method was called).

Most importantly, JUnit and Mockito do not allow for statements like "test this for any input": Statements like `any` only exist so you can say "when I receive any parameter, take this action" or "check that a method was called with any parameter".

So now your examples:

```
/* BAD */ monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), anyString());
```

This doesn't work because `monitor` is real, so `anyString` is out of place. Your mock is fine there, though, because you're supplying a mock implementation to test a real implementation.

```
/* BAD */ monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), eq(anyString()));
```

This is the same problem as above, but doubly so: `eq` should take a real value, never a matcher like `anyString`.

```
/* BAD */ monitor.severe(any(MonitorEventType.class), anyString());
```

Here you've supplied two matchers into a real method call. The matchers are just a signal to Mockito, and a real implementation is processing this, not Mockito.

```
/*  OK */ monitor.severe(mock(MonitorEventType.class), "");
```

You're supplying a mocked implementation and a real string to your real system-under-test, so this is a proper use of Mockito, even if it doesn't express what you want to test.

---

Besides the use of Mockito, the real issue here is that you want to introduce *randomness* into your test. Even if Mockito were the right tool for the job—it definitely isn't—then your test might pass 90% of the time and fail 10% of the time depending on which input is picked. This will make your tests noisy/flaky at best, and may even lead your team to dismiss the value of testing in general.

Instead, pick *representative use cases or edge cases*; if you have an enum-type parameter, you can also iterate across all values and run the test once per value. You probably don't need Mockito for this, unless you can't easily create a MonitorEventType instance for some reason; then you might use Mockito to create a fake MonitorEventType for interacting with your real Monitor under test.

Comment: Thanks! yesterday i found already out that this was my problem, But your post makes it more clear! 

Is there an other way to achieve what I want? perheps mock(string.class) with Powermockito or just use "", although this is different then I dont care about the actual String input?

Comment: Even if mocking a String were possible, there is _never_ a good reason to. The alternatives are in the last paragraph: Pick your edge cases manually, or run all cases exhaustively. I suggest using real strings you would find in the wild, as well as `null`.